# Set NSTableView clickedRow

Tags: macos, nstableview, appkit

How to programmatically simulate Control-Click on a table view row to display the table context menu and the **clickedRow** border? Just like the Notes app does on clicking the ellipsis button.

[image]

I was able to trigger the menu by:

```
let point = tableView.convert(NSApp.currentEvent!.locationInWindow, from: nil)
let row = tableView.row(at: point)
tableView.menu?.popUp(positioning: tableView.menu!.item(at: 0), at: point, in: tableView)
```

But can't figure out a simple way of drawing the clicked row border and setting the table view's **clickedRow**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was pretty close. Seems like `menu(for: NSEvent) -> NSMenu?` does the trick:

```swift
@IBAction func showContextMenu(_ sender: NSButton!) {
    guard let event = NSApp.currentEvent,
          let menu = tableView.menu(for: event) else {
        return
    }
    
    NSMenu.popUpContextMenu(menu, with: event, for: tableView)
}
```

Comment: What is the event type? Does this work for a keydown event?

Comment: The one produced by NSButton action. Updated the code to show that it's an action handler.

Comment: And yes, it works for keyDown event, just need to properly calculate the event coordinates. The solution above relies on the current cursor position and works great for button driven events.